# MVVM view switching - new view data context not populated under after InitializeComponent

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I am developing my first WPF app and am trying to stick to an MVVM approach. I am using MVVM Light.  Its a simple app, which just displays a list of things called "Merges" and allows the user to select one and edit it.

I have MainView which is just this:

```
<Window x:Class="FileMerger.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FileMerger"
        xmlns:Views="clr-namespace:FileMerger.Views"
        xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:FileMerger.ViewModels"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="File Merge" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <ViewModels:MainViewModel></ViewModels:MainViewModel>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:MergeListViewModel}">
            <Views:MergeList/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:EditMergeViewModel}">
            <Views:EditMergeView/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentPageViewModel}"></ContentControl>
</Window>
```

and MainViewModel as follows:

```
public class MainViewModel:ViewModelBase
    {
            private ViewModelBase _currentPageViewModel;
            private MergeListViewModel _mergeListViewModel=new MergeListViewModel();
            private EditMergeViewModel _editMergeViewModel = new EditMergeViewModel();

        public MainViewModel()
            {
                // Set starting page
                _mergeListViewModel.MergeSelected += navToMergeEdit;
                CurrentPageViewModel = _mergeListViewModel;
            }

            public ViewModelBase CurrentPageViewModel
            {
                get
                {
                    return _currentPageViewModel;
                }
                set
                {
                    if (_currentPageViewModel != value)
                    {
                        _currentPageViewModel = value;
                        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(CurrentPageViewModel));
                    }
                }
            }

       public void navToMergeEdit(int mergeId)
        {
            _editMergeViewModel.MergeId = mergeId;
            CurrentPageViewModel = _editMergeViewModel;
        }
     }
```

My first view MergeListView has this event in the ViewModel (MergeListViewModel)

```
public event Action<int> MergeSelected = delegate { };
```

The idea is that when a "Merge" is selected, EditMergeView is loaded with ViewModel EditMergeViewModel, passing mergeId as the parameter.  LoadedCommand in EditMergeViewModel should be run, which gets the data to populate the ViewModel with the Merge.

An EventTrigger in EditMergeView should do this:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
            <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding LoadedCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

What I found though is that LoadedCommand is not called, although breakpoints show that NavToMergeEdit in MainViewModel is being called via the event.  I stuck a breakpoint in the constructor of EditMergeView, and found that before InitializeComponent() is called, this.DataContext is null, and after InitializeComponent() it is populated.  I believe that the Loaded event is being triggered in InitializeComponent(), but at that point the datacontext is not set which is causing the issue.

This is supported by the following in the Output window in VS, which suggests to me that the EditMergeView is not binding to the ViewModel at the correct point

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'LoadedCommand' property not found on 'object' ''EditMergeViewModel' (HashCode=31475357)'. BindingExpression:Path=LoadedCommand; DataItem='EditMergeViewModel' (HashCode=31475357); target element is 'EventToCommand' (HashCode=41172271); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')
Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in FileMerger.exe
Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' in mscorlib.dll
System.Windows.Data Error: 17 : Cannot get 'MergeName' value (type 'String') from '' (type 'EditMergeViewModel'). BindingExpression:Path=MergeName; DataItem='EditMergeViewModel' (HashCode=31475357); target element is 'TextBox' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String') TargetInvocationException:'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at FileMerger.ViewModels.EditMergeViewModel.get_MergeName() in C:\Users\JonathanS\source\repos\FileMerger\FileMerger\ViewModels\EditMergeViewModel.cs:line 270
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] index, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, Object[] index)
   at MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.GetValue(Object item, Int32 level)
   at MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.RawValue(Int32 k)'
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'EditMergeCommand' property not found on 'object' ''EditMergeViewModel' (HashCode=31475357)'. BindingExpression:Path=EditMergeCommand; DataItem='EditMergeViewModel' (HashCode=31475357); target element is 'Button' (Name=''); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')
```

What am I doing wrong?  Do I need to just call it and create the ViewModel in the View constructor and set the DataContext there? .  Maybe less elegant but would avoid this.

Comment: Is the `LoadedCommand` defined as a public property in `EditMergeViewModel`? And you don't explicitly set the `DataContext` somewhere else than in the XAML markup of the main window?

Comment: Hi thanks for replying.  Yes LoadedCommand is public and it is set as follows in the constructor of EditMergeViewModel: LoadedCommand = new RelayCommand(async () => await OnLoaded()); No I have searched for DataContext being set anywhere and nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Right luckily I had a bit of time to solve this.  In EditMergeViewModel, I was not using properties with getters and setters for the commands.  So I had for example

```
public ICommand LoadedCommand;
```

not

```
public ICommand LoadedCommand { get; set; }
```

I think the reason it needs this something to do with reflection but if anyone cares to explain why this works feel free.  For now I will mark the question as answered.